# Clojure's lazy-seq caching

Tags: caching, clojure, lazy-sequences

In [Practical Clojure](http://www.apress.com/9781430272311), the authors mention that once a lazy seq value is calculated, it is cached.

If we get a *very* large number of values from a lazy-seq, might we see an out-of-memory error? Or is there a mechanism to prevent that (e.g. older cached values are removed to make room for new ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realised elements in a lazy sequence are able to be garbage collected like any other object in Clojure, with one important caveat. You should not hold a reference to the head of the sequence. This is known as "holding the head".

In concrete terms using `doall` to evaluate the whole sequence, or storing a reference (say in an atom or a `def`) to the lazy sequence while traversing it with `map` are both holding the head.

Comment: Care to clarify how does that reconcile or relate to the mentioned caching?

Comment: I think memoising may be a better term to use than caching. As far as I know, realised seq results are never 'expired' as a cache's results may be. If you don't hold onto the head, the values in the head of the seq can be GC'd because nothing is referencing them.